# SSRS - Moving subscriptions only to new server

Tags: reporting-services

We have SSRS server which has got 100 plus reports and 95 subscriptions.

Subscriptions query are very process intensive. We want to move subscriptions to new server.

Can we just move subscriptions only to new server....

Because when you move report server database, it will include everything reports, subscription etc...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the execution plans and other metrics of the queries on the database servers? Are you running SSRS and the database engine on the same server?

Comment: SSRS and database engine are on different server. Amount of data processed/aggregated is in millions.

Comment: Please clarify. Are you referring to the SQL Agent jobs or the actual work done on the report server when a subscription is processed or the work done in the data source database to execute the queries inside the reports? What “part” do you want to move to a new server.

Comment: we mean... actual work done on report server when subscription is processed.....how can we move that.. bcos reporting server is already fully utilized in running reports